# Regex for +1 123-123-1234 javasacript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the regex pattern for: +1 123-123-1234

Current I am using `/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$/` which can validate 123-123-1234 but I have +1 followed space. So how to update the above pattern for that?

Searched on many sites, but couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `(\+1 )?` at the start: `^(\+1 )?\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

`\+1([- ])?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`

I made it so that the +1 can be followed by either a space or a dash, optionally.

Edit: here it is with the first 3 digits in optional brackets aswell

`\+1([- ])?\(?\d{3}\)?-\d{3}-\d{4}`

So, you could have +1 (123)-123-1234